# Ubuntu 14.04 display appears gibberish on my lg rd405 laptop

Tags: 14.04, display, lg

i installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my LG RD 405 laptop which contains ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 graphics card. The issue is that the display appears gibberish and distorted. I have attached a screenshot my screen to exactly describe my display.

Can anyone help in finding the issue as to where the problem lies..OS or my machine or something is missing post installation stuff ?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot looks a lot like the first corrupted screen at: [Diagnose video card problems by comparing with example corrupted screens](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html).

Comment: Hi, 13.04 is end of life and off topic, we will have to stick with 14.04 or newer to help you.

Comment: installed 14.04 too...the same problem occurs in it except for the fact that only the top menu bar is distorted in it rather than whole screen.

Comment: I removed the 13.04 references ;) Have you tried installing any of the proprietary drivers to see if it goes away?